# ionic google maps api autocomplete gets Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How can I write this script correctly on ionic?:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&libraries=places"></script>
```

Does not accept the '&'

Comment: Have you tried `&amp;` instead?

Comment: Thats right! thank you very much @Regis Kuckaertz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML has few special characters, but when they appear in “content” they should be encoded using an entity reference:

- & as `&amp;`
- < as `&lt;`
  Etc.

It turns out & is the special character that introduces one of those, so that explains why some parsers trip up when they see them unencoded in URLs.

Browsers are lenient so when they encounter an ampersand in a URL they know how to fix it; which I suppose has it’s pros and cons.